# The result of elasticsearch using jest api has double quotes("value") but I want to get just value for sure

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

guys.
I've struggled with something really weird. I want to get the result of Elasticsearch query, data(inside source). So this is a part of my code.

```
SearchResult result = jestClient.execute(search);
    JsonObject json = result.getJsonObject();
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();


    for (JsonElement jsonElement : json.getAsJsonObject("hits").getAsJsonArray("hits")) {
        JsonObject _source = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("_source").getAsJsonObject();
        String orderNumber = _source.get("orderNumber").toString();
        String equipmentCode = _source.get("equipmentCode").toString();
        map.put(orderNumber, equipmentCode);
    }
```

The thing is the value of `orderNumber` is `"ABCDE"`. What I expected is `ABCDE`. (To make it clear, both String contain the double quotes with the value... The funny thing is shown in the debug mode.

I've just checked the values in _source, it has the first value of String `"A"` still... but the first value of orderNumber is `"""` and the second value is "A"... I don't know how to resolve this and anyone helping me?

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering for myself and ppl who will have the same problem. I should have used `getAsString()` instead of `toString()`... hope that I saved your time